# String with commas and references table?

Tags: sql-server, string, vb6

I have a legacy VB application that we are maintaining. A design decision we took was to store certain data points as concatenated strings. This change is set in stone as the majority of code is complete.

I'm running a loop through an array of values. What I'm doing is, looking up a LABEL for each value in a reference table. I need to be able to display the values in one label. I'm having a difficult time concetenating the values into a string and then displaying it in a label. Here is my code...

```
If strField = "Expenditures" Then
      If InStr(1, strOldValue, ",") > 0 Then
              strArray = Split((strOldValue), ",")
                    For x = 0 To UBound(strArray)
                        For Each item In strArray
                            strMessage = DLookUp(1, "Label", "tblText_References", "ID = '" & item & "'
**''''******here I'm trying to save teh value in strMessage, however, at next item, I need it to be added to strMessage in some fashion, with a (,), I'm not sure how to do it. There are anywhere from 2 to 4 ITEMS i might have.**
                        Next item
                    Next
       End if
End if
```

Comment: Ugh. This is just awful. Don't store delimited values like this. It violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of pain and anguish. You will have to use dynamic sql to unravel this which is very likely going to open yourself to sql injection. You be better off to store each value in its own row, then you can use a join to retrieve all the values for a user.

Comment: check to see if it's the first time through your loop. If not the first time, strMessage = strMessage & "," ...

Comment: Also, it looks like this is Access VBA. Is that correct?

Comment: @barry17 - with the very small snippet you've provided, it is fairly difficult to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: this is all the code that's needed. I created a new variable called strNEWmessage. The answer is: strNewAnswer=strNewAnswer & "," strMessage.

Answer (score 9):

You should definitely reconsider how you are storing the meal data.  Never store multiple values in a single column concatenated by commas.  Instead, you want to create a table to contain the selected items, which can then be `JOINed` to other tables, utilizing a one-to-many relationship.

The following code shows an example of how you might accomplish this.

Create a table to contain `Users` who will have `Meals` associated with them:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Users
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , UserName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Create a table to describe the `Meals`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Meals
(
    MealID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Meals
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , MealName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Create a junction table that joins the `Users` to their `Meals`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserMeals
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL
    , MealID INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT PK_UserMeals
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID, MealID)
);
```

Insert a sample user:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserID, UserName)
VALUES (1, 'Test User');
```

Insert the 4 meals:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Meals (MealID, MealName)
VALUES (80, 'Breakfast')
    , (81, 'Lunch')
    , (82, 'Dinner')
    , (83, 'Snack');
```

Insert some sample rows into the `UserMeals` table that associate meals with users:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserMeals (UserID, MealID)
VALUES (1, 80)
    , (1, 81);
```

Show the users with their associated meals:

```
SELECT u.UserName
    , m.MealName
FROM dbo.UserMeals um
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON um.UserID = u.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Meals m ON um.MealID = m.MealID;
```

The results:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for your effort, however, I am storing the values with a comma as a string. I'm already using them in multiple places within the application, so at this point it's too late to store it in a different way. This is the last thing I have to do with it, basically display the values that were previously saved. I'm thinking of making an array of the values, and running a loop with a dlookup function for every time that was saved, then concatenating it to display in a textbox.

Comment: Hopefully your system never has a lot of rows, and never gets really busy.  If it does, you're going to suffer long and hard for that design decision.

Comment: You may want to look at [Aaron Bertrand's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) great article on [how to split your data](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score -1):

this is all the code that's needed. I created a new variable called strNEWmessage as string. I already had a variable called strMessage as string The answer is: strNewMessage = strNewMessage & "," strMessage